# Grails Run-App Hotdeployment disabled after upgrade to 2.2.1

Tags: grails

I am having some issues while running my Grails App in the "run-app" mode. Before the upgrade to 2.2.1 the Controllers, Views and CSS will update right after I modified them. Since I upgraded to the last version this behavior disappeared.

Do you know why this is the case?

Thanks,
Nicolas

Answer (score 0):

So, I fixed the problem by updating to the last version of IntelliJ (from 11 to 12). It seems like somehow IntelliJ 11 is not compatible with the last version of Grails.

Kind Regards,
Nicolas.